# Bypassing LDAP for JUnit

Tags: java, jersey, ldap

We need to bypass the LDAP security on our web application to run JUnit tests.

We have a REST web service built in Java using the Jersey framework and using Tomcat 8.5 as our application server. All the endpoints work, but the time has come to add unit tests. We want to test every darn endpoint five ways from Tuesday, for obvious reasons. We're going to use JUnit to do such.

The problem is, our website is secured via LDAP. There's no way to get around it, except entering a correct username and password. This, of course, is impractical. Is there some way to bypass the LDAP security while we run our JUnit tests? We're not allowed to modify the security implementation in any manner, but we're allowed to bypass it programmatically if that's at all possible.

I know I'm probably missing tons of needed information here, but I know next to nothing about the security implementation, just the REST endpoints, which I wrote.

Is there an easy way around the LDAP? Do I need to provide any additional information?

Comment: What part of code is doing the actual authentication? Can't something just be mocked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Jersey Test Framework for running your unit tests without starting the container. This also should allow you to bypass any security as your tests are controlling test instance configuration.

Pretty basic tutorial: http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/jax-rs-unit-testing/

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this (I thought I posted this comment days ago, but it looks like it disappeared).

Comment: They delete such comments as they are agianst the rules )

Comment: Thanks, Aleh! That worked. Now we have working unit tests! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LDAP, the authentication can be passed off like Basic. If you know the username and password, append the header "Authorization" with the value "Basic base64_token".

The base64 token is a string that is base64 encoded with your username and password in the format username:password. Ideally, this should work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this.

Comment: Getting thrown at other stuff ATM. Will look at when I can.

Comment: Since we got the method offered by Aleh Maksimovich working, we won't be looking into this method, though it is nice to know there is another way to skin this cat.